# Android- How to perform navigation with options menu in fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, fragmentmanager

I have a fragment with item options menu in toolbar. I want to perform navigation to FilterFragment by clicking on filter menu item. Can I use a navigation graph for it or I need to use fragment manager? Is it even possible to use navigation graph? Explain me please!

Navigation graph:

[image]

filter_menu

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/filterListFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter_icon"
        android:title="@string/filters"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

navigation graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/cocktailListFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/cocktailListFragment"
        android:name="com.example.coctaildb.cocktaillist.CocktailListFragment"
        android:label="CocktailListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/cocktail_list_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_cocktailListFragment_to_filterListFragment"
            app:destination="@id/filterListFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/filterListFragment"
        android:name="com.example.coctaildb.filter.FilterListFragment"
        android:label="FilterListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/filters_fragment"/>
</navigation>
```

I've already tried using navigation component but I dont understand what view it requires

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.filter_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item,
            view.findNavController())
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

View error:

[image]

None of the variants AS offering seems to be working.